# Autovivification doesnt work even as lvalue

Tags: perl

I have this simple code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
@inp = map 2**$_, 0..6;
@cc = grep {
    my $num = $inp[$_];
    my $sum;    #---- HERE, I have to have the var declared first, before init.
    $sum += $_ for (split //, $num);
    print "$sum\n";
    $sum % 2;
    } 0..$#inp;
```

Here, the `$sum` will be used in for loop, However in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@inp = map 2**$_, 0..6;
@cc = grep {
    my $num = $inp[$_];
    my $sum += $_ for (split //, $num); # HERE, Trying to autovificate - wont work
    print "$sum\n";
    $sum % 2;
    } 0..$#inp;
```

But when I used var `$sum` at the same line with for loop - that means I am trying to declare and initiate at once - where should work the autovivifaction - As i would expect to autovivificate the `$sum` to zero (because used with math operator `+=`), but will not work, but why so? What are the rules for autovivification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not autovivification. You have a syntax mistake. If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on, it would be more obvious.

The post-fix `for` construct treats the left-hand side like a block. So there is a scope for the body of the loop. Therefore you are declaring your `my $sum` inside that loop body scope, and it's not visible outside.

If you turn on `use warnings`, you'll get *Use of uninitialized value $sum in concatenation (.) or string at ... line 6*, which is the `print` after.

You need to declare the variable first (and use `strict` and `warnings`!).

Answer (score 4):

`my` has two effects:

- At compile time, `my` declares the variable.
- At run time, `my` allocates a new variable. More or less.

The first effect is what allows you to refer to the variable until the end of the enclosing block.

The second effect means `$sum` can't possibly hold the sum at the end of the loop since you call `my` to create a new variable each pass of the loop.

---

[ *Warning: This section discusses Perl's guts. Feel free to jump ahead.* ]

But why is it undef instead of containing the number from the last pass?

Well, that's cause `my` doesn't actually allocate a new variable when executed. It places an instruction on the stack to allocate a new one *on scope exit*!

The `for` statement modifier creates a lexical scope so that `$_` can be properly restored when the statement is complete, so `my $sum` is replaced with a fresh variable at the end of each loop pass. (It's technically only being cleared rather than deallocated and reallocated thanks to an optimization.)

---

Your code could be written as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }

my @inp = map 2**$_, 0..6;
my @cc = grep { ( sum split // ) % 2 } @inp;
```

or even just

```
my @cc = grep { ( sum split //, 2**$_ ) % 2 } 0..6;
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Note that `use warnings;` would have made it more obvious that something was going wrong.

---

By the way, I don't know what you think autovivification means, but it's wrong.

Autovivification is the creation of a variable and a reference to it when deferencing an undefined value.

```
$ perl -e'
   my $x;
   CORE::say $x // "[undef]";
   $x->[0] = 123;
   CORE::say $x // "[undef]";
'
[undef]
ARRAY(0x35d7f56740)
```

Less formally, it could also refer to the creation of hash or array elements when using them as lvalues.

```
$ perl -e'
   my $x;
   CORE::say exists($h{x}) ? 1 : 0;
   my $ref = \( $h{x} );
   CORE::say exists($h{x}) ? 1 : 0;
'
0
1
```

There's no attempt to autovivify in your code.

Comment: Well I am autovivificate the `$sum` var, because I have not declared it before. That mean it is new var and I am assigning it number (value) at once. That is actually autovivification (doesnt apply only to references).

Comment: No, explicitly declaring (creating) a variable (as you did with `my $sum`) is the very opposite of automatic (implicit) creation (vivification).

Comment: OK, i thought I would have to had a value first (like `$sum = 0; $sum ...`) before actually using it.

Comment: Scalars are created undefined. Arrays and hashes are created empty.

Comment: @Herdsman it does have a value, the value `undef`.  For convenience, when you add to undef with `+=`, it is treated as 0 with no warning.  After `my $x; $x+=$_ for LIST;` `$x` will have a numeric value _unless_ the list was empty; if it may be empty, so no `+=` is performed, you probably do want to initialize it to 0 to start with.

Comment: @ysth, Not initializing means it will warn if you pass an empty string instead of a number as expected. Not initializing (i.e. keeping the default `undef`) is good here.